# Several commands in a bash loop

Tags: bash

I want to run several commands in a bash loop, how I can achieve this properly? You can see what I tried below but after executing the first command, it exited the loop. What is the correct way of doing it? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
for sample in 2 3 27 28 32
do
command1
command2
command3
done
```

Comment: You need to give more details about the actual commands being run, and the full script you're trying to execute. Your code sample is correct, that is the way to run commands in a loop; but it could be exiting for several reasons - `set -e`, an `exec` command, a `break`, etc.

Comment: Works as expected here.  http://pastebin.com/0BZVuqp7

Comment: Please show the **actual code**, since the pseudo-code works.

Answer (score 1):

Since the pseudo-code in the question [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122606/several-commands-in-a-bash-loop#comment42750266_27122606), here are a number of possible issues based on the environment and the contents of `command1`:

- The script is running with `errexit` set, and the exit code of `command1` is non-zero. To test this, try `echo "$-"` - if there's an `e` in there, `errexit` is set.
- The shell is FUBAR. Could anyone else have modified the shell?
- There's a crazy `alias` somewhere, making `command1` run something other than what you think it is running.
- `command1` runs `break`, `exit` or `continue` (or `return` if it's in a function).